# Discrepancy in estimating boundary stencil for finite difference method

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, boundary-conditions, numerics

I am trying to estimate the FD stencil for boundary as mentioned in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sanjiva_Lele/publication/222488464_Lele_SK_Compact_Finite_Difference_Schemes_with_Spectral-like_Resolution_Journal_of_Computational_Physics_1031_16-42/links/559ea0ee08aea946c06a3842.pdf) (section 4.1)  using MATLAB. The stencil order (6th) is higher than the one mentioned in paper (4th).
$$ f_1' +\alpha f_2' = \frac{1}{h} (c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 + c_3f_3 +c_4f_4+ c_5f_5 + c_6 f_6 + c_7 f_7 )$$
Each term of both sides is expanded using Taylor series expansion and then derivatives are matched to estimate the coefficients [$c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7$ and $\alpha$].

I solved the above system as following:
[image]

Above system of equation can be written as M*x=y

Note:

1) The alpha was taken to the left to form a part of unknown vector x

2) the factorial on both side were simplified and adjusted to right side.

I wrote following code for solving the above system of equation.

```
LM = zeros(8);                
LM(1,1:7)=1;                LM(1,8)=0;  
LM(2,2:7)=1:6;              LM(2,8)=-1;
LM(3,2:7)=(1:6).^2;         LM(3,8)=-2;
LM(4,2:7)=(1:6).^3;         LM(4,8)=-3;
LM(5,2:7)=(1:6).^4;         LM(5,8)=-4;
LM(6,2:7)=(1:6).^5;         LM(6,8)=-5;
LM(7,2:7)=(1:6).^6;         LM(7,8)=-6;
LM(8,2:7)=(1:6).^7;         LM(8,8)=-7;
y=[0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0];
x=LM\y;
rats(x)
```

which gives completely different answer than reported one. Both are given below:

Solution i.e. $x =[c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7, \alpha$] by

MATLAB estimated solution:     [-69/20, -17/10, 15/2, -10/3, 5/4, -3/10, 1/30, 6]

Solution reported in literature: [-197/60, -5/12, 5, -5/3, 5/12, -1/20, 0, 5]

Any help is appreciated.